# IList(Of T).Sort help

Tags: vb.net, generics, ilist

```
Dim classCodeDetails As List(Of ClassCodeDetail) =     
    db.ClassCodeHeaders.Single(Function(cch)
        cch.CLCH_ID = classCodeHeaderId
    ).ClassCodeDetails.ToList()

classCodeDetails.Sort(Function(c1, c2)  
    c1.Make.MAKE_English.CompareTo(c2.Make.MAKE_English)
)
```

My question is how can I sort on multiple attributes? I want to sort first by `Make.MAKE_English`, then By `Model.MODL_English`.

How do I implement that?

Thanks,
~ck

Comment: It always helps to get a good reply if you tag with what language you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to sort in-place, you could use the `OrderBy` function:

```
Dim sortedList = list.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Prop1).ThenBy(Function(x) x.Prop2)
```

Your example would be:

```
Dim classCodeDetails As List(Of ClassCodeDetail) = _
   db.ClassCodeHeaders.Single(Function(cch) cch.CLCH_ID = classCodeHeaderId).ClassCodeDetails _
  .OrderBy(Function(c1) c1.Make.MAKE_English) _
  .ThenBy(Function(c1) c1.Make.MODL_English) _
  .ToList()
```

In fact, this is the correct way to do this (seems you are using LINQ to SQL) since it'll use `ORDER BY` in the generated SQL statement to sort data instead of manually sorting it on the client.